# Showing step by step using images in single frame

Tags: beamer, graphics

I would like to show an series of images in a step-by-step manner (PowerPoint like) in `Beamer`. Currently, I just create a series of frames with one image for each:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Main Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/image1.pdf} \\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/image2.pdf} \\
\end{frame}
```

I read that there is a way to layer text e.g. alert highlights by using \altert<2>{This is important!}. I tried to use this code to follow this example, without success:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<1>[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/image1} \\
    \includegraphics<2>[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/image2} \\
\end{frame}
```

Is there a better way? This can mean a lot less code with 5+ `images` in a sequence. This also has the advantage that the handout would only have the last one in and not the entire progress --- saving me a lot of slides that students would not need to print. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to loop over the images of course, for example, with `\foreach` from `pgffor`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \centering
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
    \includegraphics<\x>[scale=0.5]{a_\x.jpg}%
    }
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. I now found that my earlier complainted about <1> did actually work, but this is far better with more flexiblity... Tnx!

Answer (score 4):

It is intentionally copied from [Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268187/87876) but with a little bit modification. Community wiki is enabled to compensate the copyright issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \centering
    \foreach \x/\y in {1/a,2/b,3/c} {\includegraphics<\x>[scale=0.5]{example-image-\y}}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cool. I will put it in my collection of tips and tricks :)